# Bootstrap carousel not aligning in the center

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am developing a carousel with `bootstrap`, and the aim is to have 5 images shown and every time it slides, it advances of 1.

The issue I am actually having at the moment, is that the elements are not displayed inside the box and the transaction is not clean.

This is the complete [code](http://www.bootply.com/NwnMZUJ27y). Someone know how to fix the issue?
Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

try this (customise to your preference):

```
<div id="imgCarouselSlider" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#imgCarouselSlider" class="active" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
            <li data-target="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li data-target="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
            <li data-target="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide-to="3" ></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/carousel-img1.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/carousel-img2.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/carousel-img3.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/carousel-img4.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide="next">
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#imgCarouselSlider" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

if it doesn't work; just add a container div on the outside.

Comment: Does not seem to solve the issue, you just added some controllers to slide the images.

Answer (score 0):

Remove class `col-md-offset-3` from your container ^_^

Comment: Thanks man! Seems to have solved the issue with the inline display, but I still get a strange animation effect.

Comment: Yeah, I can see something weird going on, I have no idea why it is happening. Frankly, it would take me less time to build a new one rather than trying to figure out why :P

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am forced to make the slider work with Bootstrap. Maybe it is something connected with the javascript. I will try to figure out why.

Comment: Bootstrap is awesome! carousel is really simple to implement.

Comment: Tell it to my client dude :) I know pretty well, owl carousel is actually one of the simplest to use.

Comment: Well, show him this post, I guess that's the only way I can tell him hehe -_^